# Problema de labirinto em JAVA

Tags: java

Estou com uma dúvida, preciso criar um programa que consiga encontrar a saída de qualquer labirinto em java. O método que estou tentando desenvolver é este:

```
public static void encontraCaminho(){ 
      int k = 0;
      int pos;
      int aux = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i<LINHAS;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<COLUNAS-1;j++){
          if(k==0){ //verificando se é a primeira execução
            k++;
            labirinto[INICIO_LINHA][INICIO_COLUNA] = 2; // mudar espaço vago para um espaço percorrido
            labirinto[FIM_LINHA][FIM_COLUNA] = 2;
            j = INICIO_COLUNA;
            i = INICIO_LINHA;
          }
          if(labirinto[i][j]== 0){
            labirinto[i][j] = 2;
            if(labirinto[i][j+1]==0){
                aux++;
            }else if(labirinto[i+1][j]==0){
                aux++;
            }else if(labirinto[i-1][j]==0){
                aux++;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Preciso de alguma lógica ou ponta pé inicial para realizar este projeto. Agradecido desde já;

Comment: E qual é o problema da sua implementação? Tem alguma dúvida específica?

Comment: Eu gostaria de uma lógica para seguir o caminho e conseguir encontrar a saída o jeito que usei neste método não funcionou..

Comment: Sugiro que dê uma lida em tipos de busca (profundidade, em largura etc) como ponto de partida.

Comment: Por favor inclua o código completo da sua aplicação, de forma que ele possa ser compilado e executado. Isso vai facilitar bastante a compreensão do seu problema.